# For each row in a view, show a list of entities with entity reference field pointing to that row's content?

Tags: 7, views, entities

For instance, say I have an Author node and multiple Books with entity-reference to that Author. How can I make a view showing each author with a list of their books?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a list of referencing content for each row in a view, use [views_field_view](http://drupal.org/project/views_field_view) to pull a secondary view into the row.

Add a secondary view with the fields to list and a contextual filter to receive the nid of the content being referenced from each primary view row.

Add a "Global: View" field to the primary view and use [!nid] for the contextual filter in View Settings to pass each row's nid to the secondary view.